# Is there a way to filter push replications (from local Android DB to the server) in Cloudant?

Tags: android, couchdb, cloudant

I'm a newbie on Cloudant developing an Android application that makes use of the spectacular Cloudant DaaS.

This app has only one DB with several types of documents (let's say *doc_type_1* to *doc_type_5*). In my case I only want to replicate (push to the server) some specific type of docs (lets say *doc_type_2* and *doc_type_5*) while the other are just stored in the local DB.

I've found that this is an straightforward option when using Couchbase Lite as it explains in its [documentation](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/replication/index.html). But I haven't found anything in [Cloudant Sync for Android](https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android) documentation (it seems it's only possible to [filter pull replications](http://cloudant.github.io/cloudant-sync-eap/docs/latest/index.html?com/cloudant/sync/replication/Replication.Filter.html)).

Has anyone faced this same problem? I suppose this is a very common necessity, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filtered push replications are not supported in sync-android.

There are a number of ways around this though. For example, if you know you will only ever want to push those specific document types, you could use a separate datastore for the types you don't want to push, or manage your own SQLite database, depending on your use case.

However that being said, filtered push is a supported feature in the iOS version; CDTDatastore (See [this line](https://github.com/cloudant/CDTDatastore/blob/master/Classes/common/CDTReplicator/CDTPushReplication.h#L138)), could you raise this issue on Github, so we can prioritise to bring this feature to sync-android too.

Comment: Thanks! I also thought of creating two datastores although I wanted to be 100% sure before making a workaround.